# Magnetometer causing lag?

Tags: android, compass-geolocation, sensors, magnetometer

I'm developing an application which will use magnetometer data for interaction, by moving a magnet towards and away from the phone. This works fine (enough), but it seems like when I move the magnet too close to the phone, a noticeable lag occurs, and these messages are being spit out to the log:

Tag Message
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_START
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_REQUEST
AK8973 HRET = AKSC_HOF_DSS_COMPLETE

This can be also demonstrated for example in the app "Compass 3D" which is available on Market. It is enough to move a headphone in direct contact with the phone, it will produce a lag for at least 4-500 msec, and the messages above printed to Logcat. This is on my HTC Hero.

Any ideas as to what is causing this lag, or how to work around it? Does this occur on other phone models too?

All ideas and/or theories will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the AK8973 is the magnetometer:

[AK8973 - 3-axis Electronic Compass - Asahi Kasei Microsystems](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/219477/AKM/AK8973.html)

Looks like it's complaining about the strong field, maybe kicking off a calibration routine?

I note this define in the code:

#define AK8973B_PERIOD 500000000 //0.5 sec

Comment: That sounds very plausible! But is there no way of controlling this value from software running under Android? In that case, there's no optimal way of controlling the phone with a magnet, which otherwise would be possible.